# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, pinia

Getting this error while using mapState in vuex

```
computed: mapState(['count'])
```

where else it is working fine when use like below:

```
computed: {
    count () {
        return store.state.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to version issue. After downgrading to vuex 2^ its working fine.